# Hide parent object without hiding the instanced children?

Tags: parent, instances

I have a cube, added a cone which I parented to the cube and instanced on the faces of the cube. Is it now possible to make the cube disappear?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncheck *Display Instancer* to hide the cube in the viewport and/or uncheck *Render Instancer* to hide the cube in the render.

[image: Instancing properties]

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I could have missed that, it is even on my screenshot:)